# Get Date from Fire base Server Timestamp and display it on ionic 3 app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I want to get current date from firebase server and display only date in ionic 3 app.not device date and time. i tried many ways but it all got failed.

```
this.currentTimeStamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

I don't know above approach is correct or not.but i tried.

Comment: i think i got the point for why **this.currentTimeStamp** always getting undefined . because  if I were to do something like
let dateCreated = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
there would be no value until I did something else like
this.af.database.list('/users').push({ uid: uid, dateCreated: dateCreated });
at which point a new user is pushed to the database with the date that the user was created.

Comment: How to get date from firebase server date

Comment: How have you initialized firebase in the app ?

Comment: Yes @DelwynPinto

Comment: I asked **how** have you initialized it. Which plugin ?